# Find out why a post was downvoted?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, downvotes

I just earned about 15 rep points. And then one 
of my answers was voted down and I lost two points. I think it be nice to know the reason why it was downvoted. Is there a way to find out, or is this just a missing feature?

Comment: Feature-request: mind reading. I wouldn't mind having that feature either! Sadly, anyone can downvote for almost any reason, and sometimes you'll just never know what that reason is.

Comment: See also, [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

Comment: Hmm, Encouraging people to explain downvotes - I've asked a question that was duplicate here, but there was 20 downvotes. Was it really fair?

Comment: @Jamie, one of the reasons in the tooltip for downvoting says "does not show any research effort". The same feature request has been posted *a lot*, so users get pretty tired of seeing it. Hence the downvotes. Expectation being "research effort" should have found the duplicate

Comment: Yes, and as I've ask a duplicate of it before, @mhlester, I'm not going to get interested of this question :: I hope epople will continue to downvote it.

Comment: I've opened a detailed feature-request regarding explanations for downvotes, please see [Revisiting Optional Explanations for Downvotes (on Questions)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531/456814).

Comment: you should check in comments for why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a missing feature. There is no requirement to leave a comment when voting down a question or answer, although it's certainly helpful to leave constructive criticism when doing the downvoting.

Comment: I would suggest to force commenting ONLY when down-voting from 0 to -1. I think no answer deserves a negative quotation unless it's blatantly wrong or offensive, and then it also deserves at least an explanation!

Comment: There should be some rules about down voting. Anyone can throw up a mindless down vote. A person may spend a lot of thought and time posting a well intentioned question, but a down vote can be cast with no effort - reading the question isn't even required. Down votes should require some effort. Here's one suggestion: after X number of down votes, require the down voter to give a 2-3 sentence answer for the down vote. If they can't put in this level of effort, their down votes really are meaningless.