# Enable Optional Anonymous Reasons for Downvotes on Questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, downvotes, downvote-reason

Yes, I'm revisiting this, ***again***, despite the many times this issue has already been discussed (see Related for links). People keep asking for it.

**Note that I'm restricting this discussion to explanations for downvotes on questions only, not answers.**

### The Last Serious Solution to This Problem is Lacking

[This is the top-voted accepted answer to "Encouraging people to explain downvotes"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2373/163250) (**from July 4<sup>th</sup>, 2009**):

> The comments are there for people who want to explain their downvotes.
>
> The only thing I can think of is **an AJAX `<div>` reminder for users when they cast downvotes:**
>
> > Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.
>
> After the first downvote, we can't say we didn't remind them, and honestly that's as good as it gets. Forcing a comment will end in even worse results.

**This solution was okay, but it doesn't address one of the main reasons why people don't leave comments when down-voting: potential immature, petty, and misguided retaliation from the original poster**, which can (at worst) take the form of online and offline harassment (and worse).

To address the issue of misguided retaliation and forced comments, I propose **anonymous, optional comments.**

### Optional Comments Was Suggested, but Never Explicitly Turned-Down

[The second highest-voted answer to "Encouraging people to explain downvotes"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158/163250) (**from July 28<sup>th</sup>, 2009**) actually does propose an optional comments mechanism, by which the original poster can review and gain more explicit feedback about the quality of his or her post:

```
+1 concise
+1 insightful
-1 i hate python
-1 confusing
```

**I think this feedback mechanism could be helpful, but only if it remains anonymous to the original poster.** Then people can continue to freely downvote without having to worry about petty retaliatory harrasment (and other misguided things).

**I also propose that moderators, and only moderators, have access to the record of who left which explanation,** i.e. explanations are NOT anonymous to moderators. This is to help resolve instances of abuse of custom reasons (see more in Mockup).

### Anonymous, Optional Comments Mockup

Here is a mockup. On every question, add an "explain" link, as shown:

[image: Explain link]

**For people downvoting,** this would bring up a dialog with some pre-made reasons for why people would downvote a question:

[image: Reason dialog]

Some of these pre-made reasons come from [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you think reasons should be added or removed, please explain in a comment or an answer.

There is also an option to leave a custom reason.

**For the original poster,** clicking the "explain" link will bring up another dialog, or take them to another page, which has a table with all of the (anonymous) explanations for downvotes, as well as the number of people who voted based on each reason:

[image: Reason table]

The original poster has the option to flag custom reasons for moderator attention (much like as with comments) if, for example, the custom reason is rude/offensive, or contains garbage like "laskjfaoigaefj".

**Since users won't be anonymous to moderators, users who abuse the custom reason option can be banned** from using the optional explanation feature altogether (much like a review ban), or perhaps even be suspended for egregious abuses.

### Options for Experimentation

1. Perhaps as a test of this feature, the custom reason can be left out, and if the new feedback system demonstrates itself to be good, the custom reason feature can be implemented later.
2. Instead of only giving downvoters only one choice for a downvote reason (via radio buttons), make it an option to leave multiple reasons for a downvote (via checkboxes). When I downvote a question, it's often because of multiple issues, not just a single one.

### What Do You Think?

Thoughts? Is this a good idea? A bad idea?

### Related

1. [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/163250).
2. [Allow users to leave an anonymous comment when voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6521/163250).
3. [@Downvoter sends a notification to all downvoters for your post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37123/163250).
4. [Is asking reasons for downvote in comments non-constructive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252826/456814).
5. [Require to leave a comment explaining reasoning for downvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253519/456814).
6. [Make commenting obligatory for the first downvote on a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/456814).
7. [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252235/456814).
8. [A suggestion to the “Downvote and go” thing that that turn off new users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253527/456814) (requires 10k rep privileges to read).
9. [Should downvote-without-comment rate remain unpublished?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193762/163250).
10. [Getting to Know Stack Overflow's Voting Culture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251487/456814).

Comment: I don't hate this, but isn't it largely covered already by the current close reasons (which already are supposed to be an explanation of what's wrong)? It seems to almost do what you are suggesting, with the exception of anonymous comments.

Comment: @Pekka웃 not all bad questions get closed. In fact, some are even upvoted to a net-positive score!

Comment: @TheQZ not going to lie, I'm having a hard time coming up with a counter-argument against your very good point. But then we're just stuck. Users frequently ask for more explanations and feedback regarding downvotes, which other users frequently won't give to them because (1) anonymity protects downvoters, enabling them to vote more freely and accurately, and (2) giving explanations for every downvote takes additional time and energy. So I'm not sure what to do `:/` Is it just not possible to have both?

Comment: @TheQZ keep in mind, however, that the comment system I propose **isn't 100% anonymous.** Moderators still have access to who leaves custom downvote reasons, so it's not like there's no consequences for abusing the feature.

Comment: @Mat alright, well then what about leaving out the custom reasons, and only making the pre-made reasons available, as I suggested under "Experimentation"?

Comment: I guess this would be useful to pinpoint exactly which part of "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" I *really* want to drive home?  Meh.

Comment: -1 for "one of the main reasons why people don't leave comments when down-voting: immature, petty, and misguided retaliation". +2 for those nice mockups.

Comment: @bjb568 I don't understand your disagreement with "one of the main reasons why people don't leave comments when down-voting". Care to elaborate? Do you think it's not true? What other reasons are there, besides the fact that it also takes additional time and energy on each question and downvote?

Comment: Some people just put so little effort into their questions that they don't need comments. It isn't that we're always "immature and petty".

Comment: @bjb568 I meant that the people who are being downvoted could potentially be immature and petty. It's teh Internet. That's like a given.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I thot you were talking about the downvoters, not the downvoted. Ok, then that gives you a +2 from me. :P

Comment: If everyone who downvoted also closed-voted (that had the power to), this would be nearly the same thing. Closing a question forces a person to edit their post before it can be answered. So why not stress more close-voting on sight?

Comment: @gunr2171 the issue is more about feedback regarding downvotes on questions. In particular, the feature I propose provides **immediate** feedback. Voting to close doesn't provide feedback until the question is actually closed, which often doesn't actually happen, and if it actually does, it's often after a relatively long period of time.

Comment: @Cupcake, so, if the delay to fully close a question was quicked, would this solve the problem? Say more people were closing more often. It would certanly help out with [this other discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow). (And i'm just tossing this idea around)

Comment: @gunr2171 you're asking for more effective question closing. That's quite a big issue all on its own. Anyways, not all questions will be closed, so they will have no feedback for downvotes that way.

Comment: @Cupcake, another thing I'd like to point out is that most questions that are downvoted are from users with < 15 rep, and even more common is that it's the user's first question. I've seen so often that the OP will post a question and walk away, even if we add comments for clarification. Seeing they are the majority, will this make a difference?

Comment: Recently, there was a discussion about what to do when you *do* provide a downvote comment and are then attacked by the asker.  I've seen this a lot, and is why I almost never actually mention downvoting when also happening to downvote and comment.  We really are damned if we do and damned if we don't.  I'm not sure if the canned response form would be helpful here...

Comment: @Cupcake - As far as I am concerned, this proposal could be remade on the global meta site. I fear though it may not have better luck even there.

Comment: I like this:  "an AJAX <div> reminder for users when they cast downvotes" Since it's optional and reminds the downvoter that they can help to improve the answer, I think it's useful and a good idea.

Comment: @DeborahSpeece that's already implemented, I argue in the feature request that it's not enough.

Comment: @Ben **the explanations are optional!** If you don't want to leave an explanation, the number of additional clicks is `0`!

Comment: This is the eternal dilemma distinguishing between who's a genuine ignorant (or somewhat lacks acumen) and who's spamming/being too lazy/exploiting and taking advantage of others.Teachers and professors are facing this all the time although they have an advantage: they get to know their students and they can be screwed once, hardly twice. On SO you don't know who's behind the question and thus you can't know if he's genuinely a newbie/not an internet expert user or if he is a lazy guy posting junk because he doesn't want to spend 10 minutes of his time reading the FAQ or doing his homework

Comment: I don't particularly mind this except I feel that it will increase the level of noise. What if OP decides to argue into the ether about the anonymous reasons for the downvote? Now we have to go flag those comments as "too chatty"

Comment: @Cupcake agree with this - it'll make downvotes much more useful to the OP. I would shorten the text in the comment list though. e.g. for the first point, the text "Not enough information" is sufficient and quicker to scan through when reviewing posts. I'd also add "Off topic", "Just google it" and "No question asked" as options, and drop the custom idea (you can always leave a comment if you have something more specific to say). Dropping anonymous custom comments also reduces TGIFT abuse.

Comment: @Cupcake: who do they argue with now when they ask the internet why they got downvoted? It won't fix the problem

Comment: This seems to be a solution in search of a problem. I don't see the benefit in adding complexity.

Comment: @CodyGray personally I could care less. I only bring it up because, like I said, people keep asking for explicit explanations for downvotes `:P` This is the best solution that I could come up with so far.

Comment: Have you considered the solution that involves saying "no"? That's the best one I've come up with. If you're judging what's a good idea based on frequency of request, your next proposal will be a way of contacting individual users. :-(

Comment: I don't think I've made a strong case for implementing this request `:/`

Comment: You've made this too complicated.  All you really need is a dialog that pops up with a single textbox when the downvote button is clicked, allowing the user to put in an optional explanation for the downvote.  The system would then post a comment attributed to the Community User.

Comment: Absolutely not.  Anonymity is not helpful here.  Explain in a regular comment or don't.

Comment: SE sites use rep to determine when people are ready for certain privileges. I suggest that this holds true to "downvote commenting" as well. This should be required for the newly privileged downvoters until a certain rep level is achieved then it becomes a suggestion(optional). This way habits of leaving a comment when down voting are trained/encouraged/learned/formed early on.

Comment: @Archangel33 probably not going to happen [without more buy in from the employees](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265769/456814).

Comment: @Cupcake Thank you for revisiting this issue. Would the community be open to **only the first downvote** be accompanied with a - anonymous if that helps - comment that assists the question? The explanation I am getting is that votes signal to other future users first and the feedback to poster is secondary. This at least adds fairness to the process, i.e. the first downvote with comment then helps the question before the avalanche of downvotes follow perhaps just following the first downvote.

Comment: @FMShyanguya see [Require a comment explaining the reason for the first downvote on a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/456814). [Poke Shog](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265769/456814) with complaints/suggestions, he's the guy in charge, not me.

Comment: @Cupcake Thank you! That's why I will never invent anything ... The illogical and intransigent position is what's driving me up the wall!

Comment: I am optimistic about this.

Comment: I can say that I have learned a great deal from questions regarding how to perform actions that may be 'bad practice' or generally doing something that isn't considered proper, when someone explains why it's bad practice or offers a better alternative.  The above suggestion isn't perfect but mostly because there is no perfect answer, however, it does allow for more EDUCATIONAL _opportunities_ than continuing to allow hit-and-run down-voting which serves no educational value while simultaneously increasing the frustration of new programmers.  :personal experience:

Comment: At the very least, I think the site should suggest that the down-voter explain why he's down voting.  It doesn't have to be mandatory but maybe the same pop-up as when you try to up-vote yourself.  Ignoring all of the anonymous trolling that plagues the internet, there is significant educational value to understanding why something is performed _incorrectly_ vs. no explanation at all.

Comment: I like it also because I don't always want the OP to ask me more: I often comment on what's wrong in the post and then I get a message about "it's better now please help me" when I cannot answer the question or don't feel like helping any more on the subject

Comment: I totally agree! A downvote is not constructive and provides nothing useful. The OP does not know what he can do to improve his question. On his next question he would probably make the same mistake again. In my opinion the same aplies to downvotes for answers. Providing a reason for downvotes gives people the _chance_ to improve their post!

Comment: Absolute need. I'm mainly answering, sometimes browsing. I learn a _lot_ from the comments on my answers and I'm happy to revisit & improve. Getting downvoted sometimes is part of life & learning. Getting downvote with _zero_ hints on what someone found wrong with the answer is neither beneficial for me nor for the site itself. I can only improve my answers (& myself!) if I get clear, few-words, and if possible, anonymous comments with the answer. (Anonymous is preferred the same reasons we have anonymous questionnaires.) Could we remove 1/2 of the penalty from downvoting for those who:

Comment: <cont> for those who: 1. downvote, 2. explain (right now, with names - perhaps later, anonymously, visible only to the poster), 3. in current scenario, get one 'up' on the comment from someone else (say someone with rep >= 200 so that double-reg-hack is non-trivial)?

Comment: @Charles there's always voting correction

Answer (score 72):

I'm also one of those who are worried by downvoting newbies. I have currently 140K points and I'm pretty sure if my first questions were downvoted, I would have left SO to never return. It's one of the reasons why I stay away from Meta - the process here (and the level of harassment/mobbing I feel when I post here) are simply prohibitive for me to participate.

At the same time, I'm worried about anonymous abuse of such an option. But when I read

> This is the eternal dilemma distinguishing between who's a genuine ignorant (or somewhat lacks acumen) and who's spamming/being too lazy/exploiting and taking advantage of others.

in the comments, I started wondering how much we (don't) know. SO knows a lot about its users. Not the newbies (but they can't up/downvote anyway). So what I would like to see is an analysis how many people are downvoted and how many of those never return. A full-text analysis might even allow to identify people who simply create a new account when the first one accumulated too much "bad karma".

On the downvoter side, I want to know if there are people who simply mass-downvote for fun. So maybe a system like the "you didn't vote for a question for some time" might help: If you downvote very often, the system should a) ask you to keep it in check or b) show some of the downvotes to other users (randomly selected) to see how much they digress from the average. If too many disagree, we can either reduce the number of downvotes such people get or get in contact with them.

Note: While I feel that many newbies don't spend much/enough time writing their question, that's my limited view. Bad questions have many reasons but here are two related proverbs:

- He who asks a question is a fool for five minutes. He who doesn't ask a question dies a fool.
- There are no stupid questions, only stupid answers.

I feel that being able to ask good questions is one of the most important tools for a software developer. I also notice that even seasoned warriors often lack this skill. A simple "you bad" doesn't improve the situation. Those people need to know specifically how to improve.

That's why I feel bad about the current system. Downvoting without giving a reason, especially for newcomers, feels wrong on too many levels.

If you have a good reason for the downvote, there should be no reason not to share it. Helping people improve is another skill which is very useful. And if you don't have a good reason (Didn't understand the question? Hate people who struggle with the English grammar?), you shouldn't be allowed to downvote.

...

P.S. I hesitate to post this because I worry how many downvotes it will get me :-( Is that a good thing?

Comment: You need not worry about downvotes on the new Meta, since they don't affect reputation anymore `:)` It has been mentioned by some moderator (I think) that people tend to upvote way more often than they downvote...meaning that [people don't downvote ***enough.***](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90324/163250) It's one of the reasons why [downvotes became "free"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90927/163250), instead of incurring rep loss for the downvoter (in the case of downvoting answers), and even then I've heard that people don't downvote as often as they upvote.

Comment: I don't see how few downvotes could mean "they don't downvote enough". I feel that means that people prefer to improve a situation over mindless mobbing.

Comment: I prefer posting a comment instead of downvoting.

Comment: Sorry but you seem to take this entirely too emotional. Downvotes are "mindless mobbing", downvoters need to be kept in check, number of downvotes should be reduced, because some people could feel bad? A downvote is the most direct form of feedback - "your post is bad". People need to understand it's not a personal attack! I'd personally feel way worse about reinforcing people who ask bad questions by answering without giving any indication that (and by all means why) the question is lacking. Also, there are of course stupid questions in the context of SO, e.g. everything that's far off topic.

Comment: If however someone abuses the downvote system, we have tools in place to handle it (e.g. serial vote reversing). Of course I don't condone downvoting because of things irrelevant to question quality, but I also don't see this being a problem. I can easily run out of my daily votes just by browsing new python and java questions and downvoting anyone who obviously didn't google the name of whatever exception is thrown by their code. I'd still run out of votes restricting myself to the most common exceptions. Do you suggest I stop downvoting these and thus passively reinforce this behaviour?

Comment: @l4mpi: As I explained in my question, people don't learn how to ask good questions by some magical spell. They need to be told. Downvoting is just a cheap way to say "bad dog, down." It doesn't "actively reinforce good behavior." If these people would know better, the question wouldn't be bad in the first place. On top of that: How often have you been in a situation where someone expected something from you and you didn't know what? Did you feel that was a good or a bad situation?

Comment: Correct, people learn how to ask good questions by investing time and effort into learning how to ask good questions. People do NOT learn how to ask good questions when their bad questions are answered without even giving any indication that and why their question is lacking - after all, why should they seek to change or improve anything if asking bad questions works just as well? I doubt many askers are even interested in asking good questions as long as they get answers. And to be clear, I do try to educate OP by commenting or upvoting existing comments on all my down/closevotes.

Comment: I've been coding for 30+ years now, some of it good, some of it bad. When I reflect on my overall career I have been told a number of times by various mentors to RTFM(Read The Flippin' Manual) but they almost always told me which manual. In peer reviews when people don't like or agree with something I've done they tell me why.

Comment: @TJA Or LMGTFY but with an appropriate search term.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: There are entire pages in the [help] devoted to "how to ask a better question", along with other information in the [about] pages and here, and further handholding by commenting and babying people isn't going to make things better. If you insist on commenting to try to "urge better questions", link instead to one of the existing articles that contains all of that information *and vote to close the question until they've edited to improve it*. Questions can be re-opened easily once they've been edited.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Correct, you end up chasing away newcomers and worse, they leave without ever knowing what the needed to do.

Comment: To this I would like to add the situation when a question with already low visibility, in an area where there are very few questions/answers or documentation, gets downvoted by people who don't understand the contents (which is likely when they downvote without an explanation)... and gets even lower visibility !

Comment: I'm totally agree with this and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3892259/skynet) is my profile, I didn't made my courage to post a second question after get such mass down voting without any explanations.

Comment: It's weird when you get [4 downvotes in less than 15 minutes](https://puu.sh/CAq9w/a9bb15381f.png), when historically you rarely gets a downvote, specially in answers were you explained your solution. I can't tell if someone is just a troll and decided to downvote all at once, or if they really think my 4 answers should be downvoted. So I really think a dialog with pre-made options to explain a downvote (optional) would be nice.

Answer (score 60):

I'm pretty negative about this whole idea because of the opportunity for abuse. Any time we have to put our elected moderator team as the sole barrier between someone and widespread, unchecked abuse, we put a bit more strain on [a system that relies heavily on distributed moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling).

But there's another part that concerns me as well... I'm not convinced that the solution to folks prone to lash out at criticism is a system that gives them a nice soft punching bag. [It turns out catharsis doesn't actually work...](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/unique-everybody-else/201303/internet-ranting-and-the-myth-catharsis)

Lemme tell you a story.

Years ago, I ran into a guy on Stack Overflow who was climbing through the ranks of answerers at an impressive rate. Unfortunately, he was doing so based on very large numbers of answers that were, frankly, quite lazy: google search results, code without explanation, etc.

As we were both active in some of the same tags, I tended to run across his answers just about every day for a while - and most of the time, I'd end up downvoting them, for the simple reason that there'd be another answer on the question that *did* try to explain the solution presented. Sometimes, I'd leave a comment pointing out areas for improvement...

And I noticed something: when I commented, he'd argue about the downvote. When I didn't, he'd either put some more work into the answer or just delete it.

The arguing sucked. But what solidified my resolve to stop commenting on his posts wasn't the arguing - it was that **I got *better results* when I didn't comment!**

Over the years, I've observed this pattern again and again: folks ignoring or becoming angry at specific critiques, but putting significant effort in when they had to look to themselves to determine the areas for improvement.

Now, this is clearly not true in every case - some folks are just so lost that they need *something* to guide them if they're ever to have any hope of finding their way. And in many cases, specific technical critiques are invaluable, both to the author *and to future readers* because they simply wouldn't be known otherwise.

...But do I think it's worth remembering that comments are not a panacea for folks complaining about downvotes. Sometimes, the only solution is for the author to take a good hard look at their own work and then listen to the criticisms of the one person they actually respect.

Comment: Good insight, however, your example doesn't take into account the possibility of anonymous feedback.  If there's no one to argue with, it's much less likely that someone will argue (although, not impossible :)

Comment: Anonymity doesn't mean there's no one to argue with I'm afraid, @threed - it just means you can't follow them around arguing. Which is a small benefit to be sure, but... There's an old proverb about treating folks like children & getting back what you expect that probably applies here: if we engineer the software to cater to the behaviors of our worst users, we'll just end up with more like them.

Comment: Good point--we shouldn't avoid adding anonymous feedback to down votes simply because "our worst users" won't like it; we should probably cater to our better users, who will use the feedback to improve the site, and at the same time, protect those users who provide that feedback.

Comment: @Shog9 Thank you for the example. Aha! consideration of human nature/behavior factors in ...

Comment: I don't feel your argument is compelling. 1. I haven't seen such a pattern, yet and I comment my downvotes all the time. So maybe I haven't run into someone who fits your pattern or maybe your comments could have been different. 2. Even if this pattern applies to some people (how many?): What about the rest? What about the newcomers who desperately want (to) help but know so little, they don't even know where to start? Should we appear friendly or hostile towards them? And what behavior will make us appear the way we want?

Comment: You should (and I suspect do, perhaps without realizing it) decide whether to comment based on the context, @Aaron. Same goes for downvotes. Some situations may require one, some the other, some both - worth noting that your profile indicates you've left many, many times more comments than you have downvotes; perhaps you prefer to focus on situations where you can offer advice rather than rating? As for newcomers, I often leave comments on new user posts - and I've no wish to hide behind anonymity when welcoming someone to our site either.

Comment: Nice anecdote, but given that this guy was "climbing through the ranks", he's nothing like the typical user that this suggestion addresses.  He sounds much more sophisticated - he didn't need reasons to know why he did something bad - he already knew that, and knew he was being lazy.  Downvotes called him on it, and without a user to rail against, he was forced to improve his answers.  The biggest issue here is bad questions, not bad answers (they'll take care of themselves).  So many of the new users just don't know the etiquette or expectations here.  This could help them.

Comment: Questions are already more likely to get a comment than they are a downvote, @Gerrat. Heck, the vast majority of those that do get downvoted *also* get at least one comment. The proposal here suggests that folks would leave *more* comments if they didn't have to attach their names to them, which is probably true - and, I argue, not a good thing: if you've reason to believe your comment won't do any good, then the solution is to **not waste your time writing it** - chances are, you're probably right. My anecdote hints at one reason for this, but there are plenty of them.

Comment: Hi Shog, if this is basically [status:declined], can you add that tag to the request please? Just take off [voting] to make room.

Comment: @Shog9 - I've commented on another page on this, and I'm certainly not looking for an argument, just a vindication of the current "no news is bad news" policy on SO. A simple example of how things can go wrong: There can be no exact all encompassing "line" at which ServerFault ends and SuperUser begins. So let's say someone posts a valid well researched an thought through question, but certain people feel it is more appropriate to the other site based on their subjective "line". How is the asker meant to understand this without comment?

Comment: In my experience, people who upvote very often do so on the most basic trivial answers, whereas more sophisticated answers receive far less. This indicates, at least to me, that many (of course not all) SO users have less sophisticated requirements. Also, often, negative responses I see from users to questions, indicate clearly that the commenter has little insight into the context in which the question is being asked. Here, as the reader, I have the opportunity to go - well that comment is a bit dense, I'll ignore it. But then these same people are able to downvote ...silently. Scary.

Comment: Also, it seems to me that your premise is based on "argumentative behaviour" by people being commented on. My take is that people who attempt to justify their position with little merit are very easily identified. Secondly it is entirely possible that you missed the gist of the question and that their response in fact has merit, and possibly a minor edit may clarify the question more fully. Either way, it is not necessary to get into an argument, particularly if your comment is anonymous. You have downvoted and had your input - and even if wrongly, at least readers can form their own opinion.

Comment: Further, SO should not be preventing the potential very great benefit of (optionally anonymous) downvote comments based on the concern of "argumentative behaviour" - what it should be doing is accepting the need, and looking for ways to manage the behaviour. The only other feasible alternative in my book is removing downvotes altogether allowing well received questions / answers to bubble to the top naturally.

Comment: And finally, to all the anonymous downvoters out there: I am of strongly the opinion that it is simply lazy and selfish not to comment. If one has time to read a question feel strongly enough to downvote, then have the courtesy to say why. Gravitating to the lowest common denominator should not be something the SO community aspires to.

Comment: That the user argued back when I commented on why I downvoted happened to me too, and I agree it's annoying. I once downvoted an answer to question that had nothing to do with programming, and commented to explain that such questions shouldn't be answered. The user who posted the answer replied to my comment saying I shouldn't bump posts for nothing (even though I didn't bump anything, I just downvoted and commented). In that case it didn't matter because both the question and the answer were unsalvageable, but I see why it's not always a good idea to comment explaining downvotes.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer twice.

Answer (score 29):

Yes.

I just asked my first question, one which I think I organized well and demonstrated sufficient effort to research/answer/understand myself. It was immediately down-voted without comment. I have no idea what I did wrong, and so I'll surely do it again. This helps no one.

Comment: You're right in observing that downvotes are not an educational tool—this is what comments are for. Upvotes are not an educational tool either, mind you. They don't tell you if someone upvoted your question because they're having the same problem, thought it was clear and useful, or because they thought it was nicely formatted. Voting—whether up or down—serves simply as the means by which we *rate content*. Questions are downvoted as if to say "this one isn't particularly interesting or useful, move along". Upvotes mean just the opposite. Comments are rightly disconnected from votes.

Comment: Here's the problem: "down-votes are not an educational tool" is another way of saying "down-votes are completely useless." Comments can be used to "rate content" or say "this one isn't particularly interesting or useful, move along" AND explain why.

The problem is that a down-vote only helps readers. My question being down-voted helped readers not waste time on it (assuming for the sake of argument it actually deserved the down-vote). If the person had commented on what was lacking about it, that would've helped both readers and the author. Can't imagine how that isn't better.

Comment: How do you figure it's a way of saying that? Comments are for *dialog*, votes are for *rating*. There's no reason to have a dialog in a rating system—in fact, it's actively harmful. If you explain why, people get all worked up about it, and you start having a debate in the comments section. It's much easier to just vote and get on with your life. **Downvotes are only *supposed* to help readers. They're not intended to help the poster.** Certainly you can do both downvoting and posting a comment. I often will. But they serve different purposes and should be disconnected.

Comment: I think perspective is key here. As someone looking at downvotes as taking away rep, they seem like nasty, mean things, that should be explained. However, the SE perspective is that it's merely an indication that the question/answer should be less visible, whether that be just lower on the page or hidden outright. The fact that downvotes effect rep is only there to encourage users to write content that is worthy of being shown.

Comment: @JosephLeeSaxon note that the net effect of that question was one downvote one upvote and an answer. so you gained 3 points and a good answer ( which has not been upvoted or accepted )

Comment: @codyGray - I completely get what you're saying about separation and in a way I buy it. The challenge for me is there can be no level of certainty in the current system that the person doing the downvote has an IQ higher than a gibbon. Downvoting through incorrect interpretation or ignorance is detrimental to readers (and of course confusing for posters). The ONLY measure either readers or posters have of the veracity of downvotes is the comment. And both are currently being denied visibility of this. Surely this must be considered sub-optimal.

Comment: It is equally suboptimal that the people doing the upvoting may have an IQ no higher than a gibbon. What do you propose to do about that, @Pancho?

Comment: @CodyGray - I have no issue with upvote comments. In fact requiring comment and enhancing the UI to allow display/hiding of upvote/downvote comments could be an option as readers can "see what they want". However, certainly in my experience, upvoting is usually based on successful implementation of an answer, making the likelihood of at least partial validity far higher than downvotes - which have no success criteria increasing the risk of gibbon. My baseline perspective is that information is useful - no information is not; and renders assessing the gibbon factor impossible.

Answer (score -2):

This is now partially served by http://idownvotedbecau.se/, which has good explanations of common downvote reasons, such as:

- No evidence of a prior attempt
- No evidence of prior research
- No code in a debugging question
- Vague problem statement ("it's not working")
- Images of code or exceptions
- Wall of code
- No effort to debug
- Being unclear
- Not responding to comments
- Etc.

The articles explain why this is a problem, suggestions on how to fix the issue, etc.

I'd be in favor of having a user script or something to post explanations based on this.

Answer (score -6):

I was in the middle of suggesting this for answers and questions, and this great question is appeared in the Similar Questions part. (you presented the suggestion perfectly)

**definitely agree with your suggestion with the extent to answers also.**

---

### What is our (perfect) goal ?

to have a future big library of quality contents while everyone here is happy (who asks and who answers)

### current problem:

**Downvotes hurt.** (*specially anonymous ones without an obvious reason*).

..and if you are having great contributors who are giving their time, effort and experience, for nothing in return, but to help us and our children, and they still having bad experiences like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55538834/select-n-most-frequent-values-of-column-b-for-each-value-of-column-a/55539105#comment97786620_55539105) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55525115/how-to-hide-a-column-in-select/55525143#comment97754545_55525143), then you really have a problem in your model that you need to solve .

### but anonymous downvotes are useful because

1. they help identifying good from bad content.
2. they help improving the content by motivating the post owner.
3. it's anonymity nature is cool too and protects the downvoter.

### The suggested feature (concrete reason for downvote) will do

1. it will reduce our problem by letting the post owner knows the reasons he got a downvote for (at least from the downvoter point of view), better than leaving him confused.
2. it still protects the anonymity of the downvoter.
3. it will make the post owner focuses on the specific problem in his post and will help the reader to quickly realize why this post is bad. (Bad because ... is bettrer than Bad.)

Comment: So...a user with almost 800k has a bad experience with anonymous downvotes?  And it entirely negates the presumably, "good" experience received from the countless upvotes they received?  That seems incredibly lopsided.

Comment: @fbueckert Upvotes are not a good experience, but downvotes **without a reason** is a bad experience.

Comment: If downvotes are a bad experience, the reverse also has to be true.  The premise doesn't work otherwise.  Comments are irrelevant to that position.

Comment: @fbueckert let me rephrase my last comment, "upvotes are good experience if the content deserves, but downvotes **without a reason** is always a bad experience."

Comment: There is always a reason; check the arrow tooltips.  Your premise is predicated on that upvotes reinforce inherent value, while downvotes must be justified to devalue that inherent value, along with user experience being valued above that of content quality.  That is flawed; no content has inherent value beyond what voters deem it has, and user experience is orthogonal to curating content.

Answer (score -9):

I think this is an excellent idea, (I found it while researching for existing posts before suggesting exactly that,) and I would like to see it also apply to downvotes to answers.

From the users' point of view, it will help people to better understand what they are doing wrong.  Downvotes without a reason are ruining the stackoverflow experience for everyone.  Close votes are not a solution, because many questions are not so bad as to be closed, and yet they are bad enough to be downvoted.  Also, closing does not apply to answers.

Ready-made reasons-for-downvote that I can think off the top of my head that would be extremely useful both for those who post questions, and for those who answer:

-1 Can be trivially answered by googling / reading the documentation.

-1 Can be trivially answered by rubber-duck debugging.

-1 Shows no research effort.

-1 You cannot learn a programming language one stackoverflow question at a time.

-1 Mentions "gives me an error" but does not say which fucking error.

-1 Badly formatted / written in all caps / too wasteful with the blank lines.

-1 Too much irrelevant code / no effort was made to abstract away irrelevant concepts.

-1 Is obviously [homework](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems?cb=1) but is pretending that it is not homework.

-1 Identifiers are in a language other than English.

-1 Should be an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

-1 Crucial code missing. (So, of what type is that variable that you are having so much trouble with?)

From the site's point of view, in the eternal quest to better understand how the users think, the more information the better, right?

For the author of any given question or answer, the table of downvote-counts and explanations will be so useful that it could even be permanently expanded, in-your-face, instead of hidden behind some "Explain" link.  The "Explain" link could be useful for people other than the author of the post.

As for the answers, I am envisioning a list of ready-made reasons for a downvote which would include such obvious things as "It is just plain wrong" but also tricky answers such as "I disagree", which, if chosen, would cause a message to appear saying "Disagreeing is not a reason for a downvote, you fool!"  C-:=

Comment: Why don't you just leave a comment if you think a post can be improved? Or better yet, edit it!

Comment: @TinyGiant because the OP seems to be taking pains to explicitly specify that he is talking about downvote comments on questions only, while I am proposing downvote comments on answers, too.

Comment: @TinyGiant Many people don't leave a comment and just downvote and walk away. It would be better to make a comment mandatory to leave a reason

Answer (score -12):

Requiring, or even encouraging, comments for downvotes, is incompatible with the "be nice" policy. A downvote is not like a close vote. A downvote is the only permitted means for indicating that s question or answer sucks (rather than being merely incomplete or misdirected). Any accurate comment will essentially state "your question sucks, and by implication you do too". And, despite the "be nice" policy, we need to be able to indicate that s post sucks, as part of quality control.

Comments for downvotes increases the effort demanded or expected of those who work to improve the quality of the site. They are few, and overworked. We have no shortage of people posting crap questions. In most cases, those crap questions are unsalvageable. It's not that, with a bit more feedback, the asker could edit their question into an acceptable question. The overwhelming majority of questions I down vote are lazy homework dumps and no effort "debug me" questions.

Comment: First of all, this is an _old_ declined feature request that really didn't need another answer next to the 10 already on here. That said, this answer is incorrect. It's quite possible to explain a downvote without violating the "Be nice" policy, as shown in this very comment.

Comment: @Cerebus votes on Meta are different. As for this being declined; it has returned again. The other requests should be closed as duplicates of this. I'm posting another reason to decline the request. You disagree with it.

Comment: We actually have [a new canonical dupe target](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s) for questions like this. My reasoning also applies to main. It's perfectly possible to be nice while explaining a downvote, there.

Comment: Thanks for the dupe target.

Answer (score -15):

I agree with this proposal. In fact I was just about to submit a similar proposal and I searched for potential duplicates. But my idea was to make the reason required: when you downvote, it would open a box with set of default choices or you could enter your custom comment. Anyone can then see a table with downvote reasons and their score. Of course all information must remain anonymous.

Such proposal would improve SO because it gives very concrete feedback to OP, where downvoters feel the issue with the question. Currently downvotes may be understood as "community does not like me here". If OP can see what exactly is the problem he can learn much faster.

PS. I expect downvotes and I will not know if it is because of disagreement or because I am not native speaker and there are grammar mistakes.

Comment: I'm downvoting because of disagreement, not grammar ([I'm personally not downvoting for grammar anymore](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253780/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-because-of-bad-grammar#comment15559_253780)). Your grammar is pretty good, by the way `;)` However, your proposal for ***required*** reasons for downvotes [has already been asked before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253519/456814), [and was declined](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/250177/4). See also [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250181/456814).

Comment: I'd like to note that this hasn't been declined just once.  It's been declined dozens of times...This is the epitome of the cliched repeatedly suggested terrible suggestion.

Comment: @Leos Literak Your comments are spot-on.  I'm currently going through a round of anonymous, reasonless down votes on another stack site.  As a newbie there, there isn't much I can do besides learn a new set of -secret- rules to go by.
The fact that it is so easy to chip away at another members reputation is bothersome.  They've actually streamlined the process.
At least in a court of law one is allowed to confront their accuser.

Did Kafka help design Stack?

Comment: I genuinely try to contribute to communities like SO. Getting hit with an unexplained downvote just makes me sad.

Comment: Another excellent answer was torpedoed that would fix the fundamentally flawed downvoting system. Can I just say **SIGH**?

Comment: You can just upvote @FinalContest ;)

Answer (score -26):

Anonymous downvotes are excellent for alienating new users, and the people with a lot of rep around here purposely use them for this reason a lot. If you required them to at least leave an *anonymous* comment on their downvote, it would sway some people who are downvoting for illegitimate reasons (a lot of people) and would provide, particularly new users, with direct advice on how to better formulate future questions. Because let's be honest, the rules come down to the interpretation of the people with the most rep, they're nearly meaningless when a new users tries to ask something.

Comment: Stop thinking people use them TO alienate new users, they are to keep quality of the site up, NOTHING ELSE. Show me a GOOD question by a new user that is downvoted "for no reason" and we'll talk. Show me these "illegitimate reasons" you talk of. I've honestly not seen it. Everytime someone brings similar feedback, they can't find examples, so the problem isn't there as far as I'm concerned. I'm happy to change my mind, if there is evidence to it.

Comment: Well I just had one of your mods/users admit he was repeatedly editing my post without having read it once (out of spite) and then he deleted his comment. I don't know where you got the idea that every person who uses this website is some sort of Saint, but they're not. Also it can be difficult to show you a thread like that since users don't have to provide a reason to bury a question, how would we know if the reasons are legitimate or not?

Comment: Is this what I said? I said that new guys come in and take downvotes personally without realising they are for the quality of the site. I then asked examples of wrongly downvoted questions, which you've failed to provide. For repeated edits, if you get into a rollback war, a mod will be notified and come in and lock the post. So there are contingencies for truly malicious users (serial voting reversal, rollback locks, etc). There are malicoous ppl yes, but way more new users who don't understand the site and then get angry at downvotes.  Again, show me a good post that's downvoted....

Comment: And btw, it is possible to find. Look at downvoted questions from new users. Find one that respect the guidelines and rules, and is still downvoted. Not saying it's EASY, but burden of proof is on you, not us

Comment: ["downvotes are taken so damn personal..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/839601)

Comment: @Yelnik The mod didn't have to read the post, his edit had nothing to do with the topic, he was just removing content that didn't add to the question.

Comment: @QuestionMarks How could he simultaneously remove something that is off topic while not reading it? How did he know the edit was off-topic?

Comment: It has nothing to do with being personal or not. This whole discussion is centered around ego, like the user base of the website. It is not possible to discuss this in a functional way. You'll notice that any time someone raises a concern about the voting system, someone else will manage to link it back to ego, in this case, you claim that any person who is against it takes it personally. You cannot apply this to everyone, sorry. Your real problem here is having a full dysfunctional voting system, in that you allow down votes to have absolutely no meaning or purpose.

Comment: @Yelnik It's common on the site to remove content such as "Please help!" or "Thank you everyone for all the answers!". Many people in the community try to keep the questions simple and focused, and that doesn't require reading through the rest of the question.

Comment: Ah, see this is what I'm trying to tell you people. The fact that you can't identify your own confirmation bias is very concerning. You blindly assume that because someone is capable of editing a post, they are therefore perfect, and everything they do is guaranteed to be within the rules and of the best intentions. This is an absolutely ridiculous bias to have, and it is a flaw of reputation systems, wherein massive rep-giving circlejerks get accidentally perceived as people who are useful.

Comment: And honestly on that note, this discussion is almost pointless to have, because this immense amount of confirmation bias is deeply ingrained in this website and it's user base now, and I'm sure is fully irreversible. Rep systems only end  up creating subsets of users that essentially self-appoint themselves as gods and repel anyone else who didn't "get in" at the right time. I know you'll never believe that there's massive bias against new users, because you simply can't see that now, but there is, and it's quite childish.

Comment: @Yelnik yeah, there is likely some confirmation bias here. But you need to understand that, without SEEING A PROBLEM, it's hard to FIND A SOLUTION. Honestly, whenever a new user comes in complaining about the system, we ask for proof. What I've seen on meta so far is people complaining "BUT I GET DOWNVOTED" and then someone checks the question and goes "hmmm, but this is off-topic". Again, I'm happy to change my mind. I just lack the data to change my mind. I am the first one to say Stack is rough for newbies (check on meta, it's a statement I make relatively often). I also am the first (cont)

Comment: (cont) one to say that new users don't fully understand the system and complain about it without understanding it. A LOT could be gained from everyone being aligned. The main problem in your assertion is that "we assume everyone is perfect". This is NOT AT ALL what's happening. What I'm saying is I've yet to see a real proof that this is an issue. The person who edited without reading your post, if he did more than remove fluff, WAS out of line, and you could've flagged it. But taking ONE example of inappropriate editing and linking it to inappropriate voting isn't helpful here

Comment: There might be a slight confirmation bias here, but you're aware that there's another much more prominent confirmation bias in "THE HIGH REP MEMBERS ARE OUT TO GET ME!?" ? Because I've seen people say that someone is attacking them because off-topic questions get downvoted.... so yeah, this goes both ways. To get a GOOD conversation about this going, we need data my friend. Data no one so far have been able to provide...

Comment: (oh and for the "getting in at the right time"... I've been active on Stack since a year and a half only, and I'm gaining steady rep, without ANY hiccup, so it's possible if you stay on topic. When I had 10 rep, I wasn't getting downvoted, because I made sure I stayed on topic. It was MY responsibility as a new user to learn and abide by the system. I did it, I got through fine...)

Comment: The problem exists inside the rule itself. It is incorrect. You don't need to see the repercussions directly. You allow upvoting and downvoting without providing reason, this makes the action of up and downvoting meaningless, so you tell me how this place is different than Reddit. The only thing that's different here is people regard themselves in _much_ higher light here. If you trust people enough to remove other peoples questions that may or may not be valid, you should trust them to provide a short explanation to the person that could help them in the future.

Comment: Again, downvoting is a fine concept that can be utilizing for beneficial reasons. It is not implemented functionally on Stackoverflow.

Comment: It's not a matter of trusting people to post a comment or not. It's a matter of forcing people to do so. I don't believe anyone should be forced to provide a comment for downvoting.... And yes, I do need to see the repercussions, because you seem to assume the malicious unwarranted downvotes are a plague on this site. If they were, we'd have some kinda proof by now. Right now, I've yet to see such examples. If this was such a BIG problem, they'd be everywhere. I can show you a TON of non-commented downvotes on pure crap questions that are 100% warranted though

Comment: Oh honestly I wouldn't put it past this userbase to be so deeply deluded that any amount of direct evidence, statistical or not, would be justified away with an endless slew of mental gymnastics. Having said that, if you aren't forcing people to leave an anonymous comment, then you're Reddit. And this only works within your system because you DO blindly assume anyone with the capability to up/down vote are perfect human beings. If you DIDN'T think they were perfect, they would have to justify their decision! Trust me this is more simple than it seems!

Comment: And unfortunately, by virtue of the fact that reasons are NOT required for downvoting, you therefore allow people to downvote for ANY reason they see fit!

Comment: The up-voting and down-voting is meant to moderate the quality of the content on this site, and Stack Overflow has a lot of amazing content, the voting system helps separate the quality posts from "here's my code please help" posts. The system isn't welcoming to new users at all, but it's what consistently keeps this site as such a great programming resource.

Comment: And I need to ask this because I'm definitely not understand where anyone is coming from. Do you think you're violating human rights or something by making people leave an anonymous comment on a down vote? I mean you guys act like it's the end of the damn world to change a rule to be logical.

Comment: You think it's logical, and many others agree with you, but the majority votes against having mandatory comments.

Comment: @QuestionMarks Yes, that's essentially a derailing train. You have 1 system that simultaneously monitors and changes the "quality" of the site and the "quality" of users. Do you see how having a circular system like that can cause a problem?

Comment: side question then: What is the goal of Stack Overflow, in your mind? Because a big part of how voting works is related to this...

Comment: I'd like to think its goal is to help people become better programmers.

Comment: I've been using this site for several years now, and have very little reputation, and that's mainly because there aren't any questions for me to ask, once I boil my problem down to the real issue, someone already asked it five years ago and I find my solution. But if I ever found a real problem that no one asked, I'm confident it'd get the attention and votes it deserves.

Comment: yes, but through establishing a good knowledge base of data. The voting system is built with that in mind. You don't need to explain every single vote. The voting is built so we can, at a glance, see if the answer (question) is of worth. Comments on every single downvotes we cast becomes WAY too much, and unscalable, when the amount of pure crap questions thrown on stack is increased by people believing we're a help desk, and users who don't care for the wellfare of this site and just want their bad question answered no matter what.

Comment: comments are encouraged, and by all means, I usually leave one, seeing them as great learning tools for whoever's joining the site (linking into how I think the site can be rough for new users). I just don't think I should be FORCED to comment, especially on questions where the new user didn't even take a second to check if his question is on topic here. He comes here expecting help, he should do his homework to a certain extent

Comment: The voting system of course was built with that in mind, they just missed the mark by a _tad_, and that's fine. But try getting a pack of software developers to admit they're wrong, that's a very hard task! There's nothing wrong with downvoting a new question, leaving some comments, the guy reads them, deletes the post and tries again with the guidance in mind. This is functional because, say, some guy reads a question and goes "this guys an idiot" in his head, and clicks downvote - but wait, he has to actually come up with a _coherent_ reason now.

Comment: It's one of those things where people are probably just too lazy to leave a comment, but if they cared 25% as much about the websites quality as they claim to, this would be a no brainer.

Comment: okay. Now let me throw a hypothetical at you: You're quality driven on this site, you downvote and comment EVERY downvote. You then get called a Nazi, an asshole, a dick who just wants to walk over people. You get told "fuck off" on a daily basis, get a TON of revenge downvotes. See a lot of argumentation, and maybe 10% of people willing to improve. After a year of that.... How do you now feel after downvoting? I'm not saying we couldn't make better. I'm saying with the new user base we have, commenting everything isn't any more proper. I got told by a user (I am not even paraphrasing)

Comment: "I don't give a shit about your website's quality. Just help me out, or fuck off!". After several messages like that, you grow jaded. Anyway, since THAT is a big portion of new users, you can't force people to comment on these pure crap questions, and then get into stupid fights about it. When I believe someone is genuinely trying to understand and get a grasp of Stack, I'll comment as long as needed.... I just don't believe I should be forced to do so on every thread I downvote. If every new user was willing to improve, YES. That is SO FAR from the case though...

Comment: (btw, just so my outlook on this is clear. I upvoted the OP.... because this is an OPTIONAL comment. I downvoted your answer, because this is a FORCED comment....)

Comment: And that's why I would never suggest forcing a person to leave a comment with their username. Anonymous, and possibly showing an approximation of the person's rep score who left the comment. If someone is going to do that they can yell at 'Anonymous' all day I guess.

Comment: I don't actually use downvote functions on any websites because their implementation is logically false on every site :p, but that's fine (for instance on Reddit it is simply a tool to bury opinions that don't go along with their narrative, etc). A little more intricate here, but not far off.

Comment: *it would sway some people who are downvoting for illegitimate reasons* - Putting aside whether people do this (or how many), why do you think this would work? If the people down voting are doing so maliciously, why would commenting prevent this? There'd be nothing to force them to be honest about their down vote so why wouldn't malicious people keep being malicious?

Comment: @BSMP that's sort of the same as people who argue against safe injection sites for drug addicts. Just because the solution isn't perfect doesn't mean you allow the worst possible system to remain implemented. An imperfect solution does not mean the worst option is acceptable.

Comment: my main problem is you'll alienate those who DO vote rightfully for the minority who don't. Your example isn't like the safe injection sites for addict, it's similar to installing an alco-test in EVERY car for the minority of drunk drivers. (however alco-test is properly written in English :P)

Comment: I think the amount of upvotes dished out in this thread alone is quite telling. It is clear people give far too much implied meaning to these points. Internet points lead to internet people, and those are the worst. Anyway, we're not going to accomplish anything here in any case. I appreciate the conversation.

Comment: I'm not arguing that it's an "imperfect solution", I'm asking how it's a solution *at all*.