# SO should augment downvotes with specific, actionable, anonymous feedback to authors

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, downvotes, downvote-reason

***This is not a duplicate of the FAQ. Do not flag it as a duplicate of the FAQ. It is a response to and rebuttal of the FAQ.***

SO should augment downvotes with an optional specific *actionable* feedback to the question or answer author**, like the ones at https://idownvotedbecau.se/

The list of reasons on idownvotedbecau.se, created specifically for Stack Overflow is:

> Being unresponsive
> Image of an exception
> Images of code
> It's not working
> No attempt
> No code
> No debugging
> Missing exception details
> No MCVE
> No research
> Too much code
> Too much information
> Unclear what you're asking
> Unreadable code
> Wrong language

This list is far from definitive or final, and up for debate.

Each of these reasons links to a long-form post ([example](https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion)) that explains in detail what it means and what you can do about it. I propose adopting this format (if not this exact list of reasons).

I'm going to take a multiselect (not a dropdown) that users are encouraged to select at least one option from when downvoting as a proposed solution, and refute the arguments against it in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437) point-by-point.

I whipped up an example of what it could look like:

[image: Sample implementation]

---

#### Below, a response and attempted rebuttal to the points made in [the canonical FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin?noredirect=1&lq=1) about the subject.

> **Downvotes are, first and foremost, a content rating system.**

**They are an overly simplistic rating system.** Requiring a *specific* rating (unclear, incomplete, off-topic, etc.) would improve the quality of the rating system. A simple linear scale is not a good fit for "question quality" or "answer quality", when there are so many different ways a question can be "good" or "bad". A question might be outstandingly good in one way (thorough, well-written) and catastrophically bad in another (provides harmful advice and false information). A simple good/bad rating does not capture that.

> **In the vast majority of cases, nothing needs to be clarified.**  The tooltip on the downvote arrow already explains what a downvote means, and it is specific for questions and answers. In most cases, the "comment" in the tooltip already adequately explains the logic behind the downvote, so an additional comment would just be wasted effort and noise.

**This entire paragraph is false.** "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*" does *not* explain what a downvote means, and is *not* specific, because it gives three possible explanations and does not specify which (if any) apply. "*This answer is not useful*" is again completely nonspecific. Neither message "adequately explains the logic behind the downvote", because neither message **adequately explains what is wrong with the question or answer**.

> **Any requirement could be trivially circumvented** by entering gibberish or something nonconstructive like "this is bad". Detecting and stopping those who enter such stuff through moderation/administrative action is simply not feasible on a site with millions of users.

**At worst, a user could pick an irrelevant reason.** However, in that case, the author of the question/answer would be able to **figure out** that the feedback is irrelevant (and potentially challenge it). A downvote without explanation provides *no information* and cannot be challenged.

> **It may not feel that way to you at the moment, but downvoters are doing the site a service, and making voting more difficult would impede the site's most important quality-control tool.** Voting is ad-hoc and frictionless by design! Voting separates good content from bad, and makes the good content more visible. This is essential for the platform to work, even if it sometimes feels mean. If a vote is in error—which can always happen—the expectation is that the "swarm intelligence" of future viewers will eventually correct the problem. A single vote is nothing, really. What matters is the sum of all votes, which is why we only display the aggregate score.

**Selecting a reason is a trivial amount of friction.** Actionable feedback also separates good content from bad, and helps authors create *better content*. The expectation that "the 'swarm intelligence' of future viewers will eventually correct the problem" may be correct *on average* but that doesn't help **individual authors** that get downvotes with no actionable feedback. Some of them will improve enough to become part of that "swarm intelligence" if given the chance. If simply rejected outright, they will most likely leave.

> **Scale**. Stack Overflow gets some 12,000+ questions every day. Many of them are of poor quality or just not a good fit for the site. It is beyond human capability to respond to each one of those bad or misplaced questions with custom-tailored advice. It would drain too much time and energy from the unpaid volunteers who answer questions and help users.

**Adding one additional click (or keyboard shortcut) on a multi-select when downvoting is not arduous.** Each reason would have a link to a more detailed explanation of the reason in the help center, which would have the beneficial effect of directing the author of the question or answer to **relevant** information without the person rating the post having to write "custom-tailored advice".

> **If downvoting is made more difficult, then upvoting would need to be made correspondingly more difficult.** The system uses downvotes and upvotes to filter out the "good" content from the "bad." If consequence-free downvoting is a problem, then, logically, consequence-free upvoting is, too, because it potentially marks low-quality content as "good".

**Downvoting *already* carries a reputation penalty, but upvoting doesn't.** "Consequence-free upvoting" without "consequence-free downvoting" is the status quo, which the FAQ is *supposedly* defending. Regardless, I have no objection to requiring upvotes to select reason(s) as well (well-written, comprehensive, shows research effort, contains minimal complete reproducible example, contains exactly what I needed to solve my problem, insightful, etc.), since that could provide authors with useful feedback about *why* and *how* their questions and answers are considered valuable by the community.

> **Documentation on how to ask a good question is made easily available for those willing to read it.** Stack Overflow's rules are special and arcane, but it's not like there hasn't been a lot written on the topic; even our #1 user, Jon Skeet has written explanations on how to ask a good question. Similarly, we provide extensive guidance on how to answer questions.

**True, but not relevant**, because none of that provides an explanation as to why a **particular** question or answer was downvoted. What is a user who has read the documentation, but still gets downvoted without explanation to do?

> **Leaving a comment accompanying a downvote can lead to negative consequences, like revenge downvoting and even off-site harassment.**

**Ratings, like votes, would still be anonymous.**

> **Stack Overflow (the community, and the company) is actually doing a hell of a lot to make the place feel more friendly.** The past few years have seen tons of discussions, initiatives, UI changes, help center updates and renovations, experiments like mentoring, and more—all aimed at making starting out at Stack Overflow a more pleasant experience without compromising on quality. Actually, a lot of veteran users feel that the sites' owners are putting too much emphasis on making the site feel nice, for the sake of traffic (which translates into money) over quality. Regardless of whether they're right or not, it is not accurate to say nothing is being done. It's just a really tough problem.

**True, but not relevant.** Saying a lot has been done is far from a reason to *stop* making improvements.

> **We can't accommodate everyone.** There will always be more question-askers out there than there are competent answerers. You can't overburden the latter by allowing a huge quantity of bad or badly-fitting questions into the system—you'd destroy the entire system, and hence prevent any questions from getting answered. Not getting to ask your question on SO isn't a death sentence; many SO veterans have questions every day that they don't pose on Stack Overflow because they know they wouldn't be a good fit under the current model. The resources those veterans turn to to solve their problems are usually open to everyone on the Internet - they just take time, effort, and sometimes periods of frustration to understand. There are also other, more mentoring-oriented resources to turn to.

**It is true no site can accommodate everyone. That doesn't mean you shouldn't try to make improvements to accommodate people better.** Requiring *slightly* more granular feedback is not going to "destroy the entire system". https://www.thoughtco.com/slippery-slope-logical-fallacy-1692105

Using the heavy load on moderators and high-rep users due to SO's inadequate moderation tools and feedback systems to justify not improving SO's moderation tools and feedback systems is counterproductive.

Note: This question was incorrectly flagged as a duplicate of the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437). It is not a duplicate, but a response *to* the assertions in the FAQ. Creating a new question is the only way to respond to a FAQ.

2nd Note: It appears there is a similar feature request, [Up and down vote tags (reason categories) for the OP to improve their post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328037/up-and-down-vote-tags-reason-categories-for-the-op-to-improve-their-post?rq=1) which the author of this feature request was not aware of at the time, did not get much attention when it was originally posted, and this feature request might be a duplicate of.

Comment: _"Downvoting already carries a reputation penalty, but upvoting doesn't"_. Only for answers.

Comment: I do somewhat agree with the idea, but it absolutely shouldn't result in autonomous comments and shouldn't be an intrusive popup that we have to choose to either dismiss or use. It needs to be small enough to be outright ignored, or only display if we choose to open it.

Comment: A dropdown containing all possible reasons I might downvote something is far from feasible.

Comment: _"Adding one additional click on a multi-select when downvoting is not arduous"_ Don't forget about keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: You're also omitting one _very_ important aspect of this feature request: How is this feadback going to be shown on the downvoted post?

Comment: @Cerbrus This post is an attempt to refute that FAQ point by point. In my opinion, and as I have argued, all of the answers in the FAQ are wrong.

Comment: No. Disliking a post shouldn't be any harder than liking it. Rating content should be as straightforward as possible. Besides, we need way more downvotes on SO, I think what you propose here is not only nonsensical, but harmful too.

Comment: @KevinB These would not be comments. As an example (of a format, not a community), Slashdot has ratings "Insightful", "Informative", "Interesting", and "Funny" for each comment. They would be metadata (like tags or votes), not comments.

Comment: Well, for one, this question at least quotes from the canonical "mandatory feedback with downvote" FAQ. On the other hand, it just chooses to disregard most of the points as if they didn't matter. It also seems to assume that selecting from a fixed list of reasons, which by the way were not defined in this proposal, will satisfy those who receive downvotes. I've seen enough complaints to know that it won't.

Comment: As the specific list of reasons was now edited in, it's safe to say that most of us will disagree with it. The list is at least missing "not useful"; and some of those specified are either redundant or already exist as reasons to close.

Comment: Downvoting is not a feedback mechanism for the OP. Downvotes are a signal for future visitors that the content is not useful.  As such it can not be replaced. Those that want to comment on posts that can use a bit of extra care probably use the [auto-comments plugin](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)

Comment: @ClementCherlin - thank you for keeping the post and the discussion on the constructive side. Unfortunately, we may be past the point of no return (due to a very strained history of the subject), so the suggestions like this will be rejected outright. Having an embedded option for explaining *without* making it mandatory (read: two buttons: downvote and "give feedback") may not be a bad idea. Far from sure it will help, but we could gather some data this way at least.

Comment: @OlegValter The strained history of the subject demonstrates why this suggestion should not be rejected outright: Because the problem still exists, and no solution exists. If you don't like my solution, suggest a *better* one, not *no solution*.

Comment: "Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one." I did. This **is** the new one.

Comment: Also have a look at this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405699/11573842

Comment: Let's assume for a moment that we run an experiment (much like we did with reactions) where this feature gets implemented. The outcome of the experiment is that the number of downvotes cast significantly goes down. Do you call the experiment an success? Isn't this whole FR driven by the motivation to get rid of downvotes? If it is not, explain why not.

Comment: @Yatin. Thank you for the suggestion. Note that I did consider the past arguments: I rebutted the FAQ point by point. I did not paint voters in a negative light: I solely focused on improving the experience for **both voters and authors**. Voters have no mechanism to give anonymous, constructive negative feedback. I did not accuse anyone of being lazy or malicious. The problem is **lack of feedback** to authors whose questions or answers are downvoted.

Comment: *"Voters have no mechanism to give anonymous, constructive negative feedback."* - Of course we do, votes. And votes aren't primarily intended as feedback for authors, so your second point in that comment is moot.

Comment: @rene: I would hope that the number of downvotes is not negatively affected by this proposal. If it is (or would be) then I would suggest limiting the *mandatory* aspect of it to questions and answers with no existing comments from users other than the author, and (for questions) no answers.

Comment: @Nick Are you saying that votes are not anonymous, constructive, negative feedback for authors, but we don't need anything else, because votes are anonymous, constructive, negative feedback for authors?

Comment: No, I'm saying votes are anonymous, constructive, negative feedback on the quality of a post in order to rate it against other similar content on the site. Nothing more. If the author considers it an indication that they should change the post that's a side effect.

Comment: @Nick Can you explain how an anonymous downvote with no explanation is in any way constructive?

Comment: I'm still not buying that an OP didn't take any of the guidance to heart before they were downvoted, but once they are given guidance after a downvote their behavior turns 180 degrees and they become self-conscientious.

Comment: @ClementCherlin Sure, constructive simply means helpful or has purpose, the votes order content in terms of quality, ergo, constructive.

Comment: @rene This entire post was motivated by https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337803/keep-linux-modules-extra-updated-without-installing-linux-firmware and if you can explain (definitively) why it was downvoted, please do. I want to know.

Comment: Why on earth does SO need to change their downvoting practice for a single downvote on your AskUbuntu post. Go post on their meta.

Comment: @Nick Sophistry is not constructive either.

Comment: @ClementCherlin If you want a different response you're going to have to ask a different question, votes _are_ constructive for that reason, it doesn't matter if you want votes to come with some form of useful feedback that the OP can actually action in order to improve it. That's not their purpose.

Comment: @rene Please don't assume that that is the only time anyone has ever been subjected to an anonymous downvote (this issue wouldn't have come up multiple times before if it hadn't), and please don't assume that my motivation for **posting** my suggestion on this issue is my motivation for the suggestion itself. I have felt this way for years, but never bothered posting, because this is precisely what I expected to happen. Meta is reliably conservative and reactionary.

Comment: @Nick Please stop arguing that votes **are** constructive and in the same comment stating that they are not *insert the literal definition of constructive here*. It's fine if you don't think votes *should* be constructive criticism. Clearly you believe they *are not and should not be*. But you keep saying that they are (and also saying that they are not).

Comment: All votes are anonymous so anyone whoever got a vote on their post has been subject to anonymous votes.

Comment: @ClementCherlin Please stop arguing that votes aren't constructive just because they don't do what you want them to do :facepalm:

Comment: @ClementCherlin - let's separate your experience and your proposal - you are not doing yourself a favour by showing others that the proposal does not come from a desire to help the network and instead out of a personal negative experience with downvotes. That's genuine advice as much as my previous comment that was made to nudge you in the "optional" direction as it is *guaranteed* that any proposal *forcing* people to give feedback will sink. Sigh.

Comment: @Nick You said "it doesn't matter if you want votes to come with **some form of useful feedback that the OP can actually action in order to improve it**. That's not their purpose" emphasis added. That is *the definition of constructive criticism*.

Comment: @ClementCherlin You seem to think that because something isn't constructive in one way it therefore can't be constructive at all. No, they don't provide constructive criticism to the OP, they're not meant to. They provide constructive feedback for the community who wants to know what's good and what's bad. Constructive means useful, it doesn't necessarily mean actionable.

Comment: @OlegValter Should I lie, or conceal my motivation? It is from a genuine desire to help the network. I don't want myself **or anyone else** subjected to this experience. If my motivation is invalid because it is, in part, personal, is the motivation of everyone who desires the status quo because they find it emotionally agreeable also invalid? Is then not everyone's motivation invalid if they have any emotions at all on a topic?

Comment: @Nick I see the problem. I should have written "Voters have no mechanism to give anonymous, constructive negative feedback **to question/answer authors.**", which is what I meant.

Comment: @rene Anonymous downvotes not accompanied by *any other feedback*.

Comment: The tooltip has all the feedback you need.

Comment: I think the most useful thing that would come out of this would be some metrics on how few people actually edit their post in a meaningful way after receiving comments (or closures). In my experience <10% probably <5%.

Comment: @rene Edit: If it did, you would have simply downvoted this post and not commented. Clearly it didn't. Original comment: Please don't tell me what feedback I do, or don't, need. I addressed that point (that it does not provide *any* constructive feedback) in the proposal.

Comment: @Warcupine I would love to see that information. I would also like to see how users that get downvoted without comment compare in terms of return visits and future contributions vs users who get specific, actionable feedback.

Comment: I would support a trial but, thinking back, I'm sure there is a dupe somewhere.  I may even have suggested it myself...

Comment: @ClementCherlin re: data - that sounds like something that could (probably) be done with SEDE if you up for the task, but the query will certainly be quite complex. The only thing I am pretty sure is impossible is correlating votes to comments as votes are exposed with a lot of limitations.

Comment: @ClementCherlin - and to address your previous response: no, I only meant that personal motives don't go well with controversial feature requests in my experience. You should know that - you've been around longer than I am. P.s. I don't find both sides of the argument particularly appealing because you keep revolving around irreconcilable positions: Those who think "everything is fine" will never concede to mandated feedback, but the other side refuses to take into consideration that far from everything is about the post author. Thank you for at least going for the "optional" [1/2]

Comment: [2/2]  variant in the end. I, for once, would be interested in such an experiment (emphasis on the experiment part) to see if it changes anything for the better, but only on the grounds of data and not arguments for/against voting without giving feedback.

Comment: I like the idea of being able to give anonymous feedback along with (or orthogonal to) a downvote. As long as it were optional and did not make downvoting any more difficult or awkward. One of the main reasons not to tell people what's wrong with their post is that you're putting yourself on the hook to be blamed for downvotes.

Comment: I don't really see the point of this. If there's some actionable suggestion to make – just comment. I've found the vengeful OP just as much of an exaggeration as the sneering SO. If there's nothing actionable to suggest, some canned anonymous comment isn't going to change that. The only suggested, useful canned comments seem to be *close* vote reasons; the OP gets informed of them anyway.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't have any aversion to commenting. I've never encountered a vengeful OP. The point is to get people who currently *do* downvote without commenting to leave *some* sort of indication to the author of why their question or answer is "bad". I want to see people who write "bad" questions and answers encouraged to improve, not driven away.

Comment: @ClementCherlin And I don't see how just leaving *some* information is any improvement. All the suggestions are variations of close vote reasons, with the exception of "Wrong language" (I've never seen these not getting comments) and "Being unresponsive" (not a quality issue of the question/answer!). Providing unhelpful information in addition to downvotes is arguably worse than just downvotes.

Comment: In other words: That the downvotes system isn't ideal is one thing. That <specific change X> is an improvement is an entirely different thing.

Comment: this sounds a bit like [annotations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322525/165773), "an optional set of anonymous meta notes on the post that can be picked from some predefined list"

Comment: @MisterMiyagi There's plenty of advice on meta telling people "Don't comment, just downvote and move on." Even if you feel comfortable adding comments (I do sometimes as well), there still might be plenty of people who don't, especially in the face of advice telling them not to.

Comment: Also the worry about commenting isn't necessarily about the OP being vengeful; it might just be not wanting to be castigated by someone who sees your criticism as an insult or a barrier to them getting their answer. That happens all the time.

Comment: Users say they want extended information about downvotes until they actually get it, then tend to become umm...'argumentative':(

Comment: @ClementCherlin 'I've never encountered a vengeful OP' https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366733/758133

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that it would not be beneficial to the platform in the long run. In short, this falls into wanting more than voting was designed to do, introducing an anonymous feedback mechanism which does not encourage voting (potentially the opposite), makes a tighter link between feedbacks and downvotes, and without fixing the core problem of people taking downvotes personally. All of this under a principle that not everyone agrees with: that you should explain your downvotes ([you should not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777)).

I will quote some of the takes in the question, not with the intent to exhaustively counter-argue every statement made, but to clarify my stance described above.

> The list of reasons on idownvotedbecau.se, created specifically for Stack Overflow is:
>
> > Being unresponsive 
> > Image of an exception 
> > Images of code 
> > It's not working 
> > No attempt 
> > No code 
> > No debugging 
> > Missing exception details 
> > No MCVE 
> > No research 
> > Too much code 
> > Too much information 
> > Unclear what you're asking 
> > Unreadable code 
> > Wrong language

We are unlikely to be in full agreement with that list. Even after a good deal of discussion, finding a list of reasons that every stakeholder would say "OK, let's go with that" would not be so easy. For starters, *"not useful"* is one of the key reasons presented in the downvote button's tooltip, and yet is not on that list. Some other reasons seem either the kind of feedback that is:

- Very likely provided in comments already when applicable (Wrong language);
- Incorrectly suggesting a hard rule to downvote ([No code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291399/is-there-really-a-universal-code-requirement));
- Not even based on the content of the post (Being unresponsive);
- Already provided anyway, once the question is closed (Unclear what you're asking, No MCVE);
- Possibly not different enough to justify a separate item (Image of an exception vs Image of code; No attempt vs No research, No code vs No MCVE vs Too much code).

Not to mention that idownvotedbecau.se is not an official resource and [is not even that well endorsed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355950/is-idownvotedbecau-se-recommended). Comments linking the site are known to disappear quickly, in spite of the useful information within.

> **They are an overly simplistic rating system.** Requiring a specific rating (unclear, incomplete, off-topic, etc.) would improve the quality of the rating system. A simple linear scale is not a good fit for "question quality" or "answer quality", when there are so many different ways a question can be "good" or "bad".

A linear scale is eventually required for knowing how to sort answers by vote, and when to hide questions. The part where it improves the quality of the rating system is subjective.

> **This entire paragraph is false.** "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" does not explain what a downvote means, and is not specific, because it gives three possible explanations and does not specify which (if any) apply. "This answer is not useful" is again completely nonspecific. Neither message "adequately explains the logic behind the downvote", because neither message adequately explains what is wrong with the question or answer.

A downvote is not meant to convey a specific explanation. In fact, as already mentioned, *"not being useful" is indeed a reason to downvote*, even when it is not necessarily actionable. If this option is not listed, then you are basically passing a different, incomplete idea for when to vote down. If it is listed and people use it, the authors will still be upset anyway, at the risk of perceiving this option as an insult to injury if they take it personally. This last matter is an education problem, not solved by any kind of feedback mechanism.

> **At worst, a user could pick an irrelevant reason.** However, in that case, the author of the question/answer would be able to figure out that the feedback is irrelevant (and potentially challenge it). A downvote without explanation provides no information and cannot be challenged.

There is a very serious problems with this argument.
**Downvotes are not meant to be challenged.** If a user legitimately found the post worthy of a downvote, then no justification is in order. The only exception comes from fraudulent voting, which is only rarely the case, and in that case you should reach out to a moderator via flags, not to the voter. If an author of a post sees the downvote, or any other feedback, as not applicable, they can just shrug it off (see [Tim losing his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397)). Even this assessment of whether feedback is irrelevant is not always best done by the author of a post, but this is only a matter of assuming good will first. Is someone suggesting that the question not have an MRE? Inspect the question for what you may have missed. Mistakes can happen sure, but so many times we witness askers insisting that their question is fine, to the point that they refuse to incorporate suggestions clearly given in text. It would not have been very different from comments in this regard.

> **Selecting a reason is a trivial amount of friction.** Actionable feedback also separates good content from bad, and helps authors create better content. The expectation that "the 'swarm intelligence' of future viewers will eventually correct the problem" may be correct on average but that doesn't help individual authors that get downvotes with no actionable feedback. Some of them will improve enough to become part of that "swarm intelligence" if given the chance. If simply rejected outright, they will most likely leave.

Again, downvotes are not designed as feedback to the author. The idea of correlating a downvote with a set of reasons from a multi-list is... pretty much an attempt to make it a feedback mechanism, in a platform where the last thing people should be doing is to [argue about whether a downvote is warranted or not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312634). The rest is just "the OP wants feedback", which unfortunately is not always true, as already hinted in the FAQ.

> **Downvoting already carries a reputation penalty, but upvoting doesn't.** "Consequence-free upvoting" without "consequence-free downvoting" is the status quo, which the FAQ is supposedly defending. [...]

Hold up. Voting has been deliberately designed to be frictionless, be it up or down. The penalty for casting a downvote on answers (previously on any kind of post) only existed as an attempt to prevent abuse. Eventually, as the site realized that we should be [optimizing for perls rather than sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), the penalty was removed for downvoting questions. This penalty has also been recently indicated as [one of the things discouraging downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398537). Nowhere does the FAQ defend this penalty, or explicitly claim to defend the current state of things "just because".

> What is a user who has read the documentation, but still gets downvoted without explanation to do?

Sounds almost like a rhetorical question to me. **Just a user** is the answer.
That they may feel that they should have the right to an explanation is a problem of false expectations.

> Ratings, like votes, would still be anonymous.

At least that, but it wouldn't prevent comments like "The blind downvoter who said there's no MCVE should have their eyes checked". Insults of this sort are found (and deleted) still fairly often, but they are still bad and cause harm to the already scarce curator base. This proposal would not change that unless people are properly educated to stop taking [downvotes so personally](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253227/how-can-we-discourage-over-downvoting-on-questions/253230#253230), and stop trying to [find or extrapolate who downvoted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post). Or again, trying to challenge downvotes. This feature would emphasize the correlation of downvotes with feedback, thus being counterproductive to this goal.

The only way to prevent this is to *enable this form of feedback without having to vote*, but that in turn would be paradoxal, because selecting these options would suppose that it makes sense to downvote the post. There would be a risk of people doing one and not the other, thus not downvoting where it's due. It would at least make an interesting research topic to know how often this would happen. Hopefully without much head rolling in the process. At best, give multi-select-like feedback with no voting required a trial for a month, and let SO withdraw some conclusions from there.

---

An [experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408656) was made specifically for providing private feedback to articles, not very different from what was proposed here. Other than the reasons already stated above, there are many more for the poor reception of this mechanism:

- It annoyingly pops up when voting down (again, heavily correlating votes with feedback).
- The feedback is private, meaning that only the author of the article gets to see it. At least with comments one can see when the same reason has already been given.
- Even though the feedback itself is private, it does not make the user anonymous to the author.
- It follows a weird assumption that feedback provisioning mechanisms are more relevant in articles rather than Q&A.

See also:

- [Collective Article downvote pushes for explanation. Bug or new feature?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408656)
- [Enable Optional Anonymous Reasons for Downvotes on Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531)