# Collective Article downvote pushes for explanation. Bug or new feature?

Tags: bug, feature-request, collectives

When downvoting a collective article a pop-up ask for feedback:

[image]

The same pop-up comes when pressing the "Provide feedback" icon:

[image]

It's a long established consensus on SO that downvote doesn't require explanations.

So now I'm wondering whether the pop-up after a downvote is a bug or whether it's a change of practice.

Yes, I did notice that I can skip feedback during downvote but still it's kind of pushing for feedback which is not what we normally see.

If it's a new feature, please read this as a feature-request to get the new feature removed.

Comment: If the upvote doesn't require an explanation, I'd class that as the bug.

Comment: @VLAZ That's because upvotes are inexplicable.

Comment: @JeanneDark Yep, I can believe that. Saw a question that said "what's wrong with this code", the answer was "missing semicolon". Both had a total of 8 upvotes between the two. Can't explain that.

Comment: This was copied from the failed Documentation project, launched several years ago. Exactly. We had the same objections then, too. (How is the downvote different from leaving feedback? Does leaving feedback implicitly downvote? Why are we now effectively required to leave feedback when voting? Etc.)

Comment: Really bugs me that the feedback isn't anonymous, and that the "skip" button is applied the traditional styling to make it less appealing to click. It's essentially de-anonymizing some votes -- feature or not aside, I consider that a problem and directly contradictory with how voting is meant to work

Comment: What happens to the feedback. Is it automatically converted to a comment? Something like "ABC, DEF and GEF think that this post is incorrect" maybe. Is the downvote still counted if one does not click on anything afterwards?

Comment: @Trilarion _"Is it automatically converted to a comment?"_ Unlikely because it says it's private. _"Is the downvote still counted if one does not click on anything afterwards?"_ Yes, and it will also still be counted if you click "Skip".

Comment: @41686d6564 what happens if you don't click anything? Is the vote still recorded? As in, you downvote, you get the prompt and you then leave the page without clicking either "Submit feedback" or "Skip"

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, the vote is recorded the second you click on the arrow. When the pop-up appears, you can choose to click away, click "Skip", or simply close the page. In all those situations the vote is still recorded. You can easily test it yourself and then undo your vote (at least that's what I did). Note that you don't have to join the collective to vote on articles.

Comment: What's with the different voting section design

Comment: I wasn't around for the Documentation project, but since Articles are designed to be longer-form content, which in theory may require more effort to put together, having another feedback option in addition to downvoting or commenting actually sounds like a good thing to me. The strong aversion to downvote feedback is well-known, but articles aren't Questions or Answers, they're a little different than traditional posts, so I think having feedback that's in turn a little different might be fitting and a good thing.

Comment: @zcoop98 I think the OP is fine with the feedback button. It's just the fact that the feedback dialog pops up _automatically_ when the downvote button is clicked. I'm not really against (or for) this if it's kept exclusively on articles but I can see why it's a concern.

Comment: @KevinB It's how web design keep generating jobs. New design, new bugs, new hires to fix the bugs, new design, new... It's job insurance.

Answer (score -31):

Thank you for your comments and feedback. This behavior you’re seeing is for articles only, the idea behind it is to encourage people to give the author feedback in a private manner on what can be improved upon so that they can make the necessary changes to the article. This is, as you mentioned, more of a “change of practice”. If somebody thinks there is something wrong with the article, we’re giving them an extra opportunity to help solve the issue.

To clarify further, this is newly implemented on articles only. The reason for this change is to promote and encourage giving feedback to the author when you choose to downvote. Articles are different from Q&A, we assume that most articles will take more effort and willingness from a user to write. We’d like to promote an article being edited and updated so that it can be valued as ‘high quality content’ versus all that initial writing effort going to waste. Users choose to downvote for a variety of reasons, our hope is that users will let the author know why they’re downvoting so that, if possible, the author can make the necessary changes to improve the article. Yes, this is an extra nudge to create a change of practice that we'll be monitoring closely through data and research.

Note that the downvote gets counted as soon as you select the button (while the feedback modal is displayed). You can click ‘Skip’ or anywhere outside the modal to close the feedback modal.

**Answer to ‘How private’**

The feedback and the user that sent that feedback can be seen by the author, Admins of the collective, any other users the author has added as an editor to the article and (soon to be) Mods (planned feature update coming). Your user ID shows up next to the feedback in the ‘Edit’ mode of the article. **Note** that all private feedback looks the same to the author regardless how it comes in, they cannot see if a piece of feedback was given by using the feedback button OR by downvoting and providing feedback. The downvote is anonymous, the feedback is not.

**How can private feedback be moderated?**

Most of the features that are in place for regular comments will be available (soon) to private feedback as well. We’re treating these like comments for now.

**Why not just use comments**

Not every user is comfortable leaving public comments. We’ve heard this more from newer users that are intimidated by the community (a.k.a. you fine folks ;p ) and afraid of making a mistake. The private feedback was tested in research multiple times and it received very positive results. Users liked the option of sending feedback that only the author would see versus it being public.

Again, we intend to monitor this very closely and have worked with the collective Admins around rules and expectations.

**Why not apply this to Q&A**

I think it's safe to say that a change like this on Q&A without proper research would not be the best approach. I would consider this 'change in practice' like an experiment. For now, we'd like to look at how this affects an article's lifecycle.

Comment: _"we’re giving them an extra opportunity to help solve the issue"_ Isn't that what the "Provide feedback" button is for? One can choose to click the button manually if they wish to. This does not explain why it's necessary to "push for feedback".

Comment: How private is "private"? Is that only for the commentor and the poster or does the poster not even know who is commenting?

Comment: Adding to @Scratte's question, if the feedback is so private that the poster can't see the commenter then how is such a comment moderated? Is there a feature for that..? Also why not make it public? Making it private means many people might suggest the same things over and over again instead of upvoting the previous comments

Comment: @Sabito錆兎 _"how is such a comment moderated?"_ The dialog says _"Your profile will be associated with the feedback"_ - so, it can be moderated (somehow). Also, based on how I interpret that sentence, it looks like the post author _can_ see who provided the feedback, but let's see if Carog will confirm this.

Comment: Another question: Why would I give feedback using this feature instead of just skipping feedback while downvoting and adding a comment instead. That way my downvote stays anonymous *and* I get to give the feedback I wanted. If comments are not for this purpose then what should they be used for? I feel like comments will only be for thank you comments :/

Comment: Sorry for not elaborating more the first time, the answer has been updated with more details and answers to questions raised in the comments.

Comment: Then why not have the same thing for downvotes on all posts? I get that new users are intimated by the lack of feedback, but other users are intimidated by revealing who they are. Also because it's entirely optional what's even the point? When I downvote an article I'll just skip it and there's no feedback.

Comment: _Users liked the option of sending feedback that only the author would see versus it being public._ ---> If the public sees a criticism on a post with a downvote, nobody will retaliate because it's not their post and they won't care. The author is the one who is most likely to retaliate. Shouldn't it be anonymous?

Comment: I don't quite understand the reasoning here. How is this different from "-1. You didn't link to the research"? There's a lot of post about why voting is anonymous and how quickly things can derail once you start talking about voting in the comments. "The private feedback was tested in research multiple times and it received very positive results.". Any links to that research?

Comment: "Articles are different from Q&A, we assume that most articles will take more effort and willingness from a user to write.".. Excuse me?!? It seems to me you may not have spent a lot of time on Stack Overflow, because there's some serious effort in a lot of posts there.

Comment: I hope you realize that when articles go public, feedback being non-anonymous and "forced" is gonna lead to some OPs wanting revenge rather than to take action on the feedback

Comment: I don't understand why it is only on downvotes. An upvote does not imply "wow this is 100% perfect!", it indicates usefulness. People upvoting can also have (private) feedback. Giving some people a podium and others not does not give the site a very good look, IMO. I know everyone can press the feedback button, but it's how things are made to look that causes the most confusion.

Comment: "We’d like to promote an article being edited and updated so that it can be valued as ‘high quality content’..." The same reasoning would also apply to Q&A. Also Q&A should be edited, I think. It seems a bit inconsistent to promote editing by nudging for feedback in one case but not in the other, when high quality content is the goal in all cases. Or is high quality maybe not (or to a lesser extent) the goal for Q&A?

Comment: @10Rep "..what's even the point?" [Nudging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nudge_theory). Although it's optional it still influences behavior. Could result in more feedback or even less downvotes (because people are bothered by seeing the feedback dialog).

Comment: I think it would be much much safer to experiment with this as separate "annotation like" feature, something like was proposed a while ago (by Stack Exchange CM!) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322503/165773). Experimenting with such a fundamental and sensitive feature as voting is like walking on a minefield

Comment: @gnat The minefield is very small so far. I would ask for statistics at some point about how many people use that feature, but it's no good until there are many more articles.

Comment: frankly speaking, being "afraid of making a mistake" is a problematic mindset that impeds growth in oneself (I know this all too well myself). But I firmly believe that instead of catering to it by adding an option to hide from public scrutiny, we should provide *more* venues (or improve existing ones) for public feedback. IMO, this "private feedback" feature should be scrapped.

Comment: "The downvote is anonymous, the feedback is not." - Am I missing something here? Doesn't leaving negative 'private' feedback naturally _de-anonymize_ the downvote since by leaving the feedback (with your user id attached) it's probable that you've downvoted?

Comment: @Lewis the creators of the article would have no reason to go and investigate whether or not somebody downvoted them, and they likely wouldn’t anyways because, as has been mentioned earlier, there was a lot of information given to the admins and users of the collectives.