# Add anonymous comments for answer downvotes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, downvotes

Generally I don't have a problem with downvotes, but answer downvotes without explanation are pretty annoying. For example:

1) You post an answer that you spent time working on and that you think is correct

2) You get a downvote

3) You get another downvote

At this point I'm questioning whether or whether not my answer is correct. Unfortunately there are no comments that explicitly say what is wrong or why a part of the answer warrants a downvote. I don't know whether the answer is explicitly wrong or if its just random downvotes, which makes it harder for me to improve the answer content-wise.

Asking for clarification in the comments usually doesn't result in getting clarification, and often leads to more downvotes. Personally I think people are afraid to comment because of retribution in the form of serial-downvoting, so anonymous comments can help this out.

**As the answerer of a question, if my answer is incorrect, I would also like to learn more why it's incorrect instead of a vague -1.**

**EDIT**:

This question has been market as duplicate, however the premise is that comments will still remain **OPTIONAL** and not **MANDATORY** as the duplicate suggests this is proposing, and that people who comment can choose to leave an anonymous comment.

The idea is that downvoters can choose use anonymity to explain why an answer is incorrect (which should be the main reason why answers are downvoted) without fear of serial downvotes.

This would encourage revising answers to make them better/more accurate instead of just wondering on why you got a -1.

Comment: [Strongly related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531/7296893). Your proposal is less suitable than this link, since anonymous comments can lead to more rudeness and abuse. There are many similar proposals out there.

Comment: @Andre not really a dupe of that one IMO, because this proposal is about adding the option to comment anonymously, and doesn't make it mandatory

Comment: I upvote this suggestion not because I agree with it, but because I believe your reason for not explaining the reason was absolutely spot-on. But this doesn't solve anything, we can't hide because we fear to get serial DV - There's already a daily task to revert revenge DV, and if it doesn't identify them then you can contact SO and ask them to revert it manually. This happened to me last week and it was solved after contacting SO

Comment: This system is going to be so open to abuse, it's not even funny.

Comment: Downvoted to provide anonymous comment - @$&## &&@@@##*^ ** and simply dislike that suggestion.

Comment: Besides "I dislike" could you guys provide some genuine reasons? @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ could you provide an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: To make this system of any use, comments would have to be as anonymous as the downvotes they're linked to. It's going to be a lot harder to control rudeness, sarcasm and condescension when you don't even know who's been writing them. People who want to leave constructive criticism from my experience don't need a veil of anonymity to do so.

Comment: How about users have the ability to leave an anonymous comment once they have reached a certain number of rep? Mods can still see the original commenter.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ not necessariy,  Comment authors could be anonymous to ordinary users but visible for mods.  That is not the same restriction as on voting: ATM, mods cannot see who down/up votes.

Comment: *Mods can still see the original commenter* It'd have to be really obvious when leaving an anon comment that this is the case. We want to prevent folks from leaving abusive comments, not just clean them up after the fact.

Comment: You can still leave an abusive comment anon or not. Either way a mod cleans it up or it gets flagged. It works the same way.

Comment: People will be more inclined to ignore the rules if they think they can get away with it. Hiding the name is likely to make people think that *no one* can tell who left the comment and that they can't get punished for anonymous comments.

Answer (score 4):

They are not downvoting you, they are downvoting the content. The only solution is to fix the content.

Never have I ever downvoted an answer nor question because I did not like the user. I honestly don't even look at usernames when voting, period.

---

My best advice:

**QUICKLY**

- Understand that they are not downvoting you, they are downvoting the content
- Review your post for technical or syntax errors
- Re-read OP's question to make sure you actually understood all of the requirements, parameters, and nuances. If something has been clarified which you were not aware of then your content is open to scrutiny.
- Make sure your answer is not a shot in the dark to a broad question asked by OP
- Make sure you are not hastily trying to answer a question which is bound to be closed; especially if it has a high chance of being closed as a dupe.
- Make sure your answer is not the same as someone else's; especially if your answer is timestamped after theirs.

You should probably consult this advice **before** submitting your answer.

---

If you follow all of this advice and still get flogged with downvotes then gently add a comment to your answer:

> I would like to improve my answer but I am not sure what is wrong with it, can anyone suggest how I can improve?

I have used this on occasion and find that people will tend to help you if they feel that you will take their criticism to heart.

Even if I am not the downvoter, I will sometimes leave comments such as:

> You probably got downvoted because x, y, and z.

---

Below is the average interaction when someone requests an explanation:

[image]

Comment: I'm not saying that they are downvoting me. I am proposing a system where downvoters can explain why they downvoted without fear of retribution in the form of serial votes. This has nothing to do with How to answer.

Comment: @Primusa I understand the system you are proposing but downvoting is not the issue. I tend to not leave comments on posts because my experience has been that the poster is clueless and introduces further newbie issues with their edit and asks for review, they get defensive and shut down, or they do not react. I do not fear retaliation nor retribution for my comments, I just choose not to invest more time into something that is a 99% chance of a lost cause. There is unfortunately too much garbage coming through at an alarming rate so "downvote and move on" is a common mindset.

Comment: @Primusa Please see my update for proof of concept.

Comment: This doesn't address OP's main concern though. Newbies need explanations for the reaction they're getting or they can't really learn how to improve. It's an important, and missing, part of the community as a whole.
This is still a relevant article on one of the problems that OP is trying to address: https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Comment: @Andrew I suggest developing an algorithm which detects if OP is asking downvoter to explain themselves and be shown the Advice section from my post. There is no need to hand hold and accommodate thousands of new users that fail the basics of reading rules. If you ever contribute more then you will understand the pain of how getting additional information from OP is akin to pulling wisdom teeth without anesthesia.